# How to handle "open with" without ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, ios

I have implemented "documents types" and when I open PDF in safari, I can "open with" my own application. However, I cannot get the newly imported URL, since the application is already launched and was just put in the background (Not being launched from scratch). Only "ApplicationDidBecomeActive" will be called, but without the right file url for me to process.

Anyone knows how to get the file url?

Answer (score 2):

When your application is going to open URL then `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method in application delegate is called - you must to handle opening in that method.